# remove trailing * or # from data in pandas

Tags: pandas

Im reading a csv using pandas and getting all datatypes as `object`

`NO` is the column having numeric values with trailing * and # in some observations.

I tried

```
import numpy as np
tai[np.isfinite(tai['NO'])]
```

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

How can I remove all rows which have * or # in trailing in NO columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this dataframe,

```
    No
0   1
1   2#
2   3
3   4*
4   #5
```

You can use this to remove ONLY trailing characters,

```
df['No'] = df['No'].str.replace('[#|*]$', '')
```

You get

```
     No
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4    #5
```

A more generalized solution incase you want to remove these characters from the entire column and keep only the numbers

```
df['No' ] = df['No'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False)
```

You get

```
    No
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```